# How change color of three btn at toolbar crossplatform

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I could not understand why the button with dots is not displayed. But clicking in this area opens drop-down menus.

[image]

The dots on the button are white and they just blend in with the background. I found a solution for android, but how do I go about making a cross platform solution to the problem?

[image]

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem 
        Order="Secondary"
        
        Text="Item 0"
        Priority="0"/>
    <ToolbarItem 
        Order="Secondary"
        Text="Item 1"
        Priority="1"/>
    <ToolbarItem 
        Order="Secondary"
        Text="Item 2"
        Priority="2"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell what you're doing because you haven't posted any relevant xaml/code.

Comment: @Jason I added code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the Order property is set to Secondary, behavior varies across platforms. On UWP and Android, the Secondary items menu appears as **three dots** that can be tapped or clicked to reveal items in a vertical list. On iOS, the Secondary items menu appears below the navigation bar as a horizontal list.

A easy is to change the background color of the toolbar.

App.xaml.cs:

```
 var navPage = new NavigationPage(new Page2());
        this.MainPage = navPage;

        navPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
```

[image]

**Update:**

**Android:**

Change the color of 3 dots in style:

```
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">  
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">#54FF9F</item> 
</style>
```

Use the `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` in the Toolbar.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:theme="@style/MainTheme"
android:popupTheme="@style/MainTheme.Base" 
 />
```

[image]

**iOS:**

Like what i said in previouss reply, the Secondary items menu on ios appears below the navigation bar as a horizontal list.

[image]

You could use `IOSToolbarExtensions` instead.

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/IOSToolbarExtensions/

Install it and add the code below into AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(IOSToolbarExtensions.iOS.Renderers.IOSToolbarExtensionsContentPageRenderer), Priority = short.MaxValue)]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want change color of background header bar, I want change color of button with 3 dots

Comment: I have updated my reply. Please check it.

Comment: Its work for android, what about IOS? How it will be displayed on iphone?

Comment: iOS do not support the three dots. You could use `IOSToolbarExtensions` instead

Comment: @Winteriscoming Any update for this case? Have you solved this issue?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Do you know how can i change the size of botton with 3 dots?

Comment: What if we change theme to dark? Is there a way to change dots and popup style at runtime ?

Answer (score 0):

in file **style.xml** find MainTheme and add

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">#592bca</item>
```

then in file **Toolbar.axml** add or change

```
android:theme="@style/MainTheme"
android:popupTheme="@style/MainTheme.Base"
```